# How can I intersect two collections with a table with a 2-part key, in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have input data like this:

```
FOO.A
FOO.B
FOO.C
```

BAR.X
BAR.Y

and a rules table like:

```
   (FOO = A, BAR = X) => 1  # match
   (FOO = A, BAR = Z) => 2  # no match
   (FOO = B, BAR = X) => 3  # match
```

I want to take the input data, and ask the table "what entries match this input data?", and get back rows 1 & 3.

I thought about using hashtables where FOO is the key, and the value is a hashtable with BAR as the key, and 1 as the value.  Problem is, there are duplicate keys.

What's an idiomatic way to write this in PowerShell?

Performance is not critical: the data sets are small.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm trying to use, and I think it will work

```
$table = @(
    @{ 
        Foo = "A"
        Bar = "X
        Value = 1
    },
    @{ 
        Foo = "A"
        Bar = "Y"
        Value = 2
    },
    @{ 
        Foo = "B"
        Bar = "Z"
        Value = 3
    }
)

$table | foreach {
    $row = $_

    $foo = $input.Foos | where {
        $_.Name -eq $row.Foo
    }

    $bar = $input.Bars | where {
        $_.Name -eq $row.Bar
    }

    if ($foo -and $bar) {        
        # processing
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought. Did you check Compare-Object cmdlet?